# Why didn’t the N1 use detachable boosters like the Soviet’s did on Soyuz?

Tags: design-alternative, n-1

Why did the N1 (to my inexperienced eye) have a massive rework? Soyuz, Vokshod, Vostok, Sputnik all showed that detachable side boosters worked. If side boosters work, why wouldn’t the N1 just had some really big detachable boosters (highly technical term) instead of a massive base?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I note that the tankage in the Soyuz-family boosters is in oddly-shaped tanks, not mass-optimal and maybe tricky to fabricate; each of the N1 stages contains a pair of spherical tanks with a thin shell around the pair.

Comment: "some really big detachable boosters" - the whole reason for the N1's design was to avoid having to design newer, larger engines, which would have taken time that they simply didn't have. See [this related question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/61609/39424).

Comment: @Cadence No. They would just have clustered the smaller engines on the strapons.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.astronautix.com/n/n1.html

> Configuration variations considered were:

> N1-I - Packet rocket, as used for the R-7. Six strap-ons around an identical core with an upper stage. Two sub-types were considered: In the first, as in the R-7, the rocket would hang from the 'shoulder' of the strap-ons above the flame pit to minimize lower stage mass. The second, which was selected for further study, had the same layout, but the base of the rocket was mounted conventionally, free-standing on its base on the launch pad. This was the baseline design for comparison with the others.

> N1- II - Polyblock - a cluster of autonomous rocket stages, each consisting of two propellant tanks feeding individual engine sections. Loads would be carried through the individual stage structure, although the Blocks would be tied together to form a single unit. This was basically the same as the competing Chelomei UR-700 and Yangel R-56 layouts.

> N1-III - Polyblock - a cluster rocket, but with the loads transmitted through an external skin. The tanks would be unsupported and a common fuel system would feed the engines. This scheme was analogous to the American Saturn I first stage and Nova designs.

> N1-IV - Monoblock - large single stages, each with one oxidizer and one fuel tanks, using a common fuel system to feed the engines. This was analogous to the American Saturn V and the selected N-I configuration
> All of the designs used 'hot start' stage ignition, requiring use of the familiar Warren truss open strut interstages.

> Following analysis of the designs, the following were the results of the detailed design analysis:

> Parameter  N1-I    N1-II   N1-III  N1-IV

> Payload - kg   70,000  65,000  72,000  75,000

> Complexity 16 tanks
> 8 engine systems
> 78 armatures    30 tanks
> 15 engine systems
> 621 armatures   30 tanks
> 3 engine systems
> 331 armatures   6 tanks
> 3 engine systems
> 305 armatures

> Train Cars Required    26  21  33  43

> The disadvantages of Variants I, II, and III were **the large number of servicing ports, fueling ports, and check inspection points**. It was felt that the **lower complexity and higher performance of the monoblock** Variant IV outweighed the much greater number of train-car loads of parts necessary. The gores of the spherical propellant tanks and panels of the side walls would be built in the factory in Samara and only final assembly of the launch vehicle would be undertaken at the cosmodrome.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: What a wrong with this answer?